How do I document child classes that return more specific types than parent?
I am trying to figure out how to properly document some code, mostly so that tools like PHPStan and Psalm don't complain.
Simplified, I have an abstract class that defines methods for setting and getting the state of child classes.  The type of that state might be different child class to child class, e.g. a string in one case, an array in another, etc..
In reading up on this, I figured the way to accomplish it would be to use @template on the base class, and more specific param/return types on the children.  i.e.:
/**
 * The base class, where I use a template and "mixed" param/return types.
 *
 * @template StateType
 */
abstract class hasState {
    
    /**
     * @param StateType $state
     */
    public function setState(mixed $value): void;

    /**
     * @return StateType
     */
    public function getState(): mixed;

}

/**
 * A child class, where the state is a string.
 */
class stringState implements hasState {

    protected string $state = '';

    /**
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function setState(string $value): void
    {
        $this->state = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getState(): string
    {
        return $this->state;
    }
}

/**
 * Another child class, where the state is an array.
 */
class arrayState implements hasState {

    protected array $state = [];

    /**
     * @param array $value
     */
    public function setState(array $value): void
    {
        $this->state = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getState(): array
    {
        return $this->state;
    }
}

In short, this doesn't work. I get errors like this in Psalm:

Declaration must be compatible with hasState->setState(state: mixed)
psalm: MethodSignatureMismatch: Argument 1 of stringState::setState has wrong type 'string', expecting 'mixed' as defined by hasState::setState
psalm: MoreSpecificImplementedParamType: Argument 1 of stringStage::setState has the more specific type 'string', expecting 'mixed' as defined by hasState::setState

Is there no way to accomplish what I'm trying to do: i.e. document and type the params/return values in child classes to use more specific scalar types than the parent?

Are you only looking for document or you want strong type too?

For phpdoc you are right you can use template, but you need to also specify the template value in child class.
To do so you need something like @implements hasState<type>
The problem is you can not use mixed in parent and string in child in PHP and it count as error. So that make scene that you need validation in setState
/**
 * The base class, where I use a template and "mixed" param/return types.
 *
 * @template StateType
 */
interface hasState {
    
    /**
     * @param StateType $state
     */
    public function setState(mixed $state): void;

    /**
     * @return StateType
     */
    public function getState(): mixed;

}


/**
 * @implements hasState<string>
 */
class stringState implements hasState {

    protected string $state = '';

    public function setState(mixed $state): void
    {
        // here you need validation since $state can be anything.
        // you can ignore this line if you are just want to document and don't want to check for type saftey
        if(! is_string($state)) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid value for state");
        }
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    public function getState(): string
    {
        return $this->state;
    }
}

And if you write this code you will get error by PHPStan or other tools.
$test = new stringState();
$test->setState('Test');
$test->setState(1); // this should rasied error

For checking that is working in PHPStan you can check this playground.
